# How to hide process graphics

Tags: python, graphics, process

Wanting to know about instructions on how to hide the graphical display of a process in order to save more usage.

For example: I have 2 processes both called SOME_PROGRAM.exe while having different PID(123 and 321) both displaying certain graphics, so there it is! I want they both having the graphics erased while remains the process.

Answer (score 0):

By hide graphical process do You mean starting it and then hide its GUI elements, or start it in taskbar, or start it as completely hidden process? What system? What program? Maybe check whether it have some switch by calling in terminal SOME_PROGRAM.exe /? or SOME_PROGRAM.exe -h do the job.

For second option, "start it in taskbar" You need to change the Run property of shorcut, or start program when pressing CTRL key on keyboard:
https://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/

On windows the last "completely hidden process" can be achieve by running SOME_PROGRAM.exe as an service. Some advice can be found here.
https://superuser.com/questions/1168587/how-to-run-an-exe-application-as-a-background-task-on-startup

First need hacking the GUI, You can try script written in AutoIt. This tool can dig in selected app by PID or name, and extract Handles to internal objects, finally letting You to manipulate them.